# Using relations for models with namespace in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, database-relations

How do I write relations for models with namespace?

if I have `Class Foo::Bar` and `Class Employee` and I want to have habtm between them would I write

```
Class Foo::Bar

has_and_belongs_to_many :employees

end
```

and in

```
Class Employee
has_and_belongs_to_many ???? # <- how do I write this part?
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
class Employee
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foo_bars, :class_name => "Foo::Bar"
end
```

And then you should be able to access all the `Foo::Bar` objects on an `Employee` instance with `employee.foo_bars`